# When to update store

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reactjs-flux

I have started working with reactjs, but I constantly come across this issue where I do not know when to properly update the store.

Right now what I am doing is always dispatching an action to update the store when the component is mounted, and I believe that defeats the purpose of a store since the beauty of it is to retrieve data without hitting the server.  But without hitting the server I won't know if the data in the store is the latest.  This is especially a case when two people are using the app the same time and very often when one changes something the other person might not see it until the store re-pulls the latest.

The solution I know is to integrate signalR and have it pushes update to the store as data changes, that way I can safely get from the store without worrying about stale data, but I do not have the time to implement such systems and would like to know what other quick approaches or how others are resolving this issue.

Comment: If you cannot have the initial data loaded with static data then how else would you do it? It's *very* common for a component to have a "I don't have any data yet" handler, hit the server, then render once that's complete. Even if the data was being pushed instead of pulled you'd *still* need to handle rendering before data was available.

Comment: My main concern is after having the initial data loaded, how would I be able to ensure that it is the latest?  If another person on the app is updating something after my initial pull is completed, I would be looking at stale data.

Comment: It wouldn't be the latest. If you must have the latest then you *must* push or use websockets or whatever. There's no magic; you either have the data or you don't.

Comment: Ah, ok.  I guess pushing is the only route.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I believe that defeats the purpose of a store since the beauty of it is to retrieve data without hitting the server. But without hitting the server I won't know if the data in the store is the latest.

It does not defeat the purpose, because you have to get the initial data somehow (`componentDidMount` is a great place for this to happen).

Beyond this, there are two solutions to updating your state further:

1) Listen for a WebSocket/SSE and fire the update action when it occurs (not an ASP.NET guy but I believe that's what SignalR is for).

2) Implement some sort of polling mechanism, and fire an update action with the results. You can then compare the results of the API call to your current state, and only update state if something has changed.

Assuming you have an action creator that fetches some data, you can simply call the action over and over at an interval using a timer. You can set this in `componentDidMount` just like the initial action. Don't forget to clear the timer when the component unmounts:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    this.props.actions.fetchData()

    // fire the action every 3 seconds
    this.intervalId = setInterval(this.props.actions.fetchData, 3000)
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId)
  }

  render () {
    // ...
  }
}
```